# Application of Borel-Cantelli Lemmas

Tags: probability, random-variables, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Can you help me solving the following exercise? I should use the Borel-Cantelli Lemmas, but I don't know how.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables having a continuous distribution function. Define the following two sequences of events for $n \geq 1$:

$$ A_n := \{X_n > X_i,\ \forall i \in \{0,...,n−1\}\}, \quad B_n = A_n \cap A_{n+1} $$

Compute $\mathbb P(A_n\ \text{i.o.})$ and $\mathbb P(B_n\ \text{i.o.})$. Justify your answer.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post or the posts of others.

Comment: I have flagged for moderator attention because this account was used again to vandalize the post (and attempted to vandalize the answering post).

Comment: Why are you removing the content of your question?  If you want to delete the post just delete the post.  Don't vandalize what you put up.

Comment: I can't delete it, I do what I want with my posts

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2944509/291100

Comment: @user601109 No, you don't.

Answer (score 3):

First it is not hard to see that $A_n$ are pairwise independent. Also, $\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\mathbb{P}(B_n)=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$.

Since $\sum \mathbb{P}(A_n) = +\infty$ and $A_n$ are pairwise independent, by Borel-Cantelli lemma $A_n$ happens infinitely often almost surely.

Also, since $\sum \mathbb{P}(B_n) < \infty$, again by Borel-Cantelli Lemma $B_n$ happens finitely often almost surely. Thus the first probability is $1$ while the latter is $0$.